# AngularJS parallax effect directive not applying on application load

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, parallax

I'm creating application using AngularJS + ngRoute module + Angular Bootstrap UI. I've created index.html page and few templates, that are being loaded through ng-view directive placed in index.html.

Currently I'm trying to make parallax effect on background images, based on this plugin:
https://github.com/brettdonohoo/angular-parallax

http://brettdonohoo.com/angular-parallax/index.html

In one of my views I have DIV element, that has parallax directive on it.

```
<div parallax-background parallax-offset="0.4" parallax-ratio="0.7" class="slide" style="background-image: url('{{covers[0].image}}')" ng-click="open(covers[0])"></div>
```

The problem is - when I'm loading application, the directive is fired correctly on the DIV element, but the background-position css does not change. When I scroll window - background-position changes OK. But I need the position to be applied on initial change too.

When I move my DIV element out of the template to the index.html it works. But of course I would like it to display only one one subpage.

My directive:

```
.directive('parallaxBackground', ['$window',
    function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
            scope: {
                parallaxRatio: '@',
                parallaxOffset: '@',
            },
            link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
                var setPosition = function () {
                    var calcValY = (elem.prop('offsetTop') - $window.pageYOffset) * ($scope.parallaxRatio ? $scope.parallaxRatio : 1.1) - ($scope.parallaxOffset ? $scope.parallaxOffset : 0) * $window.innerHeight;
                    elem.css('background-position', "50% " + calcValY + "px");
                };

                angular.element($window).bind('load', function (e) {
                    setPosition();
                    $scope.$apply();
                });

                angular.element($window).bind("scroll", setPosition);
            } // link function
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Try adding position:relative to the parent element